# Group_by column specific type

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a table named Garden where i have a column named item_type which has vegetable, fruits and herbs and i have one more column named item_name, which contains carrot, apple and so on.

I am using flask for a project and i am trying to display the vegetables on a webpage by running this script.

```
def vegetable():
    vegetableItems = Garden.query.filter_by(item_type='vegetable').all()
    return render_template('vegetables.html', title="vegetable", vegetableItems=vegetableItems)
```

which works fine. But i want to display each item_name with respect to its item type as a group. So in vegetable page, i want to display all carrot and all raddish. For this i tried to run this script below

```
db.session.query.filter_by(Garden.item_type).group_by(Garden.item_type='vegetable').all()
```

which does not work. Please can some one tell me what mistake i did.

Comment: what's the name of attribute that specify that this is of kind carrots or reddish?

Comment: In item_names. Also i ran this script db.session.query(Garden.item_name).distinct(Garden.item_type).all() it kind of works. Which displays [('potato',), ('avocado',), ('tomato',), ('onions',), ('beetroot',), ('banana',), ('strawberry',)]  but i also want to filter the vegatable and fruits here.

Comment: But as I can see (item_name and item_type) are two columns inside garden table, so you can access to the item_name column by vegetableItems.item_name when you iterate through vegetableItems list of objects. Why are you using group_by?